Converting Discreate survival time to continuous one
I remember that a few years ago a scientist told me that we can convert the discrete survival time in Epidemiology to continuous survival time according to the following example-method. I would be grateful if you could let me know if we can confirm this method (if so, let me know the name of the technique).
Suppose, I have a study where the patients come to the hospital every three months for check-ups. T0 (one week before surgery), T1 (Three months after surgery), T2 (6 months after surgery) up to T8 (21 months after surgery). If patient 1 has a event in the interval of 3 to 6 months (T2) then we can convert the survival time to 3+1.5=4.5. If patient 2 has a event in the interval of 6 to 9 months (T2) then we can convert the survival time to 6+1.5=7.5

This is completely ad hoc and to be avoided.  Use a discrete time analysis.

@
Frank Harrell, Dear Prof. Harrell, Thanks so much for the comment. I truly appreciate your time and kindness.
